# Testing for regular expressions in coffescript rails

Tags: coffeescript

How can I test for existence of a pattern using coffee script. I am checking the data sent from server.

Currently I am using   /false/.test(data), where data is, output data from server.

It is'nt working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You test it pretty much the same way you would with JavaScript. Some more details would be helpful. Also, what exactly does "it isn't working" mean? What is the input, the regex, and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for JS regular expression docs, such as [Mozilla's regular expression guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Coffeescript example:

```
console.log "found" if (data.search /regexpattern/) >= 0
```